# How to extend the length of a page through CSS?

Tags: css, image

I would like to extend the length of my page but i'm not entirely sure how. As of right now, I have a picture on the webpage. At the bottom of the picture, I want to place another one. However when I insert a new picture into the code, it overlaps the existing one due to the cascading style sheets.

```
.background-pic .number-1 {
background-image:   url('../resources/images/hoth4.jpg');
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-size:    109%;
height: 930px;
position:           fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color:   white;
z-index:            1;
}

.background-pic .number-2 {
background-image:   url('../resources/images/hoth2.jpg');
background-repeat:  no-repeat;
background-size:    109%;
height: 930px;
position:           fixed;
width: 100%;
background-color:   white;
z-index:            1;
}
```

Comment: That's beacuse you are using `position:fixed` both are in the same place ... Can you share your markup and how you want it to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:fixed`

and add

```
.background-pic [class^=number]{
     display:block;
     clear:both
}
```